# What does this mean in Virtual Functions?

Tags: c++

> Late binding occurs only with virtual functions, and only when you’re **using an address** of the base class where those virtual functions exist.

This is an extract from a famous text book.

My question is...what exactly does the author mean by 'using an address' ?

Comment: Funny how that exact sentence appears in http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/importedHTML/languages/C++/Thinking_in_C++/tic0155.html (Bruce Eckels Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition), and in http://goo.gl/w1TxUD (Moving from C to C++, by Arunesh Goyal).  Professional plagiarism?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with saying exactly which "famous text book" that came from. Actually, this is just considered proper quoting and being fair and respectful to the author or authors.

Comment: I agree.  Though I found two sources of the same quote, it would be useful to know what book is specifically being referenced.  Someone, somewhere has probably read the same book and knows the context of the statement better.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, credit should be given to Mr. Goyal!

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

The relevant scenarios are when you have a pointer or reference with a static type of pointer-to-Base or reference-to-Base, regardless of whether the pointer or reference is a local variable, a function parameter, member variable etc..

```
// accessed via pointer...
Base* p = new Derived(); p->fn();    // (ref.1)
void f(Base* p) { p->fn(); } Derived d; f(&d);

// accessed via reference...
const Base& r = static_derived;
void f(Base& b) { b.fn(); } Derived d; f(d);
```

> Late binding occurs only with virtual functions, and only when you’re using an address of the base class where those virtual functions exist.

The statement is misleading in two ways:

- Late binding *may* occur under the specified circumstances, but the optimiser's allowed to bind at compile or link time instead if it can work out the dynamic type involved.  For example, if both lines of code in (ref.1) above appeared together in a function body, the compiler can discern that `p` addresses a `Derived` object and hardcode a call straight to any `Derived::fn()` override, or failing that the Base-class implementation.
- The situations above involved pointers and references.  As far as the C++ Standard's concerned, the mechanisms used to implement references are left unspecified and we humble programmers shouldn't assume they're effectively pointers with different notations for use, so we shouldn't consider them to store the "address" of the variable they reference, but thinking of them as glorified pointers storing addresses is generally practical and the quoted statement's lumped them in with pointers as mechanisms "using an address".

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the emphasis is not on using an address, which would be wrong since a reference would do as well. Rather, the point is that the static type of the address or reference is that of a "base class where those virtual functions exist". This is not always the case when you have multiple baseclasses or when the baseclass hase a baseclass itself where the memberfunction in question does not exist.